# Drawable Reference Store in Database

Tags: android, database, reference, store, drawable

I have some image names stored in a database (Fully Qualified Like R.drawable. SomeImageName) Column type is Integer, but the images themselves are in the /res/drawable folder of the application.

I need to assign these images to some views at runtime, and I'm currently doing it this way:

```
SomeView.setBackgroundResource(Cursor.getstring(Image_column_Index));
```

and

```
someView.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(Image_Column_Index, null, null));
```

Neither of these methods are working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all R file is autegenerated during build time. Where do you take your db ids from?

Comment: Also what kind of "doesnt work" are you facing? Exceptions, "nothing happening" or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for R.drawable.image_name try smthing like this

```
getResources().getIdentifier("image_name","drawable", getPackageName())
```

or use

```
getResources().getIdentifier("your.full.pakage.name:drawable/image_name",null,null);
```

Comment: @Selvin is this method as efficient as retrieving the rescource by R.drawable..? Is a good idea to use it (getIdentifier() method) in an AdapterList?

Comment: It should be ... but you may always cache the results in model like `class Model { resID = -1, resName = "someName" }` then in getView `if(model.resID == -1) { model.resID = getIdentifier(model.resName); }`